# Javers fails after changing the primary key from long to UUID

Tags: javers

I have just changed the primary key of an entity from `long` to `uuid`.

Now, when I try to change an object, javers fails with an Exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 7
    at java.base/java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:215)
    at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.util.UUIDTypeAdapter.deserialize(UUIDTypeAdapter.java:19)
    at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.util.UUIDTypeAdapter.deserialize(UUIDTypeAdapter.java:10)
    at org.javers.core.json.BasicStringTypeAdapter.fromJson(BasicStringTypeAdapter.java:45)
    at ........
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.commit(JaversTransactionalJpaDecorator.java:50)
```

Javers seems to try to deserialize the old long-id as a UUID, which fails.
I could not find any recommended way of handling this situation.